# mounting an encrypted dm-raid partition on login

Tags: software-raid, dm-crypt

I have a dm-raid1 with a LUKS encrypted partition `md0` on it and I would like it to be mounted automatically when I login, using pam_mount.

So far I have configured the `pam_mount.conf.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">
<pam_mount>
  <debug enable="1" />
  <mntoptions allow="nosuid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other" />
  <mntoptions require="nosuid,nodev" />
  <logout wait="0" hup="0" term="0" kill="0" />
  <volume
    user="me"
    path="/dev/mapper/data"
    mountpoint="/mnt/data"
    fstype="crypt"
    cipher="aes-cbc-essiv:sha256"
    fskeypath="/home/data.key"
    fskeycipher="aes-256-cbc"
    fskeyhash="md5" />
  <mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />
</pam_mount>
```

Further I added `@include common-pammount` to `/etc/pam.d/login` and `/etc/pam.d/gdm`.

The problem though, is that /dev/mapper/data is not in place when it is about to be mounted. However, the mounting works if I do

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md0 data
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [PAM script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pam-script/)
to run the `cryptsetup` command at session start.

PAM script runs one of three handler scripts `onsessionopen`,
`onsessionclose` or `onauth` (depending on the event that it is called
to handle); each script is passed the user name and the invoking
service name. If you require `pam_script` in your session before
`pam_mount`, you can have `onsessionopen` do the `cryptsetup`
invocation.

Details and examples can be found at: 
http://linux.bononline.nl/linux/pamscript/01/build.html

Comment: As cryptsetup is asking me for the encryption passphrase, is there a way to make it not to and let pam_mount handle this?

Comment: According to the [HOWTO](http://linux.bononline.nl/linux/pamscript/01/build.html), adding `expose=1` to the pam_script invocation will make the password available to event scripts in the environment variable `PAM_AUTHTOK`.  So you should be able to run `echo $PAM_AUTHTOK | cryptsetup ...` to avoid being asked the password again.